# When Id change in *ngFor dynamic Routes not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, router, ngfor, routerlink

```
`<div *ngFor="let data of projects">
  <a [routerLink]="'/projects/'+data.project_id">
 {{data.project_name}}</a>
</div>`
```

[image]

Link is changing when I click on link But page Content not changed

from

**http://localhost:4200/projects/1**

to

**http://localhost:4200/projects/2**

but data remains same!

Comment: Have you check console for errors?

Comment: There is no error... First time clicked then it is properly worked but when is second time another link click it is not working

Comment: Second time this is not going in ts file

Comment: No error at all or second time error occurred?

Comment: No, there not any error

Comment: @riyajain Can you provide app.module.ts code? I need to reproduce that issue in the Stackblitz

Comment: and show the code of this `projects/'+data.project_id` route component

Comment: Actually its redirects but angular having problem to re-render the same component!

Answer (score 1):

Set `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` in app.module.ts

like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround if the `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` did not worked!

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of projects">
  <div (click)="navigate(data)">
    {{data.project_name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
......
......

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigate(data){
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyRoute', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>
       this.router.navigate(['/projects/' + data.project_id])
   );
}
```

Comment: pro_details = new ProjectDetails();

  constructor(
    private projectDetailService : ProjectDetailService,
    private route : ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const project_id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('project_id');
    this.projectDetailService.getProjectByID(project_id)
      .subscribe(response => {
      this.pro_details = response});
  }

Comment: @riyajain Add the posted code in the Parent Component TS

Comment: what do i do... I am very stuck in this. suggest me something

Comment: @riyajain Can you share the anydesk Id?

Comment: I am trying that 'sidebar.component.html' has on link and on that link i click this is route in 'show-details.component.tsl file and show data in 'show-details.component.html''

Comment: So add the above code in the `sidebar.component.ts` file

Comment: Nooo.. there is no code of this the " '/projects/'+data.project_id" is direct route to show-details.component Show my route File

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path:'home', component: HomeComponent,data: { title: 'Heroes List' }},
  { path:'sw_info', component: SwInfoComponent},
  { path:'about', component: AboutComponent ,data: { title: 'Heroes List' }},
  { path: 'add_project', component: ProjectDetailsComponent},
  { path: 'projects/:project_id', component: SidebarComponent},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

Comment: @riyajain this Code: `navigate(data){
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyRoute', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>
       this.router.navigate(['/projects/' + data.project_id])
   );
}` which provided in my answer

Comment: @riyajain Where did you use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`?

Comment: In app.module file

Comment: @riyajain Then replace that line with `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})` and test it

Comment: @riyajain Done..?

Comment: The variable that declared you -- `const routes: Routes = [ { path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, { path:'home', component: HomeComponent,data: { title: 'Heroes List' }}, { path:'sw_info', component: SwInfoComponent}, { path:'about', component: AboutComponent ,data: { title: 'Heroes List' }}, { path: 'add_project', component: ProjectDetailsComponent}, { path: 'projects/:project_id', component: SidebarComponent}, { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } ];`

Comment: @riyajain I would suggest sharing the screen will solve it in 10 min using Anydesk or Team viewer if possible

Comment: @riyajain So can you provide me the anydesk Id so will take the remote and check?

Comment: @ Prashant Pimpale wow... superb..!! thank you soo much.... it is worked for me... :)

Comment: @riyajain This is actually internally navigating to that URL `(which means URL change and then you can redirect to the original URL)`

Comment: @riyajain Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if it helped you!